# Update camera after search a place using google map

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, sdk, swift5

I am using google map iOS SDK to show map in our app, I am getting latitude and longitude from google search place API. After that, I want to update the camera position to the searched place but it is not updating. Can someone tell me where am wrong? My code for update camera as  follow:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude, longitude:  self.longitude)
let newCamera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(coordinate)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(2, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
    self.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: googleLocation!.lat, longitude: googleLocation!.long)
    CATransaction.commit()
    self.mapView?.animate(with: newCamera)
}
```

I also tried with

```
self.mapView?.camera = newCamera
```

```
self.mapView?.animate(to: newCamera)
```

```
self.mapView?.moveCamera(newCamera)
```

same behaviour

Comment: Please see my answer and let me know if it works. If it doesn't I will be able to replicate this issue on my end on Monday and help further.

Comment: @evan, thanks for replay. I tried your solutions not work.

Comment: Thanks for your update, damn I see. I will reproduce this today on the office's mac and get back to you.

Comment: Can you post all relevant code needed for replicating this issue from my side? Your posted code alone works as per the docs.

Comment: Hi @evan, I am sharing the google doc link for my google map code, please check searchPlaceFromGoogleMap() function https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DoZfonx9Mrf8XeazdFM9ZU1m9-C9DUHL-j3Pu5Oq3XU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you! I'll get back to you tonight.

Comment: I just tried to run your app with your code but it's missing a lot of external files and dependencies. Can you please provide all necessary code to run your app? Also I can confirm your code to update camera works perfectly as is on my end, so the issue must be somewhere else in your code implementation (non-related to maps code), that's why I need to fully reproduce your app to be able to help.

Comment: @evan thanks for your support! Can you possibly help via remote desktop sharing?

Comment: It's not appropriate in SO as we're community-focused, but I'm happy to help you further using code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203078/discussion-between-naresh-pawar-and-evan).

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following potential solutions:

1. First of all, make sure that you actually have a reference of your map with your `self.mapView` and that it isn't nil. Likewise with `self.latitude` and `self.longitude`, and ensure this coordinate is valid.
2. Place `coordinate` and `newCamera` on the main queue, right above `self.mapView?.animate(with: newCamera)`.

```
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(2, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
        self.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: googleLocation!.lat, longitude: googleLocation!.long)
        CATransaction.commit()
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude, longitude:  self.longitude)
        let newCamera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(coordinate)
        self.mapView?.animate(with: newCamera)
    }
```

3. If the above doesn't work, try using `animateToLocation` instead.

   `self.mapView?.animate(toLocation: coordinate)`

---

**EDIT:** After running your sample app, these are my findings:

Your app is throwing the following exception on my end:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GMSThreadException', reason: 'The API method must be called from the main thread'

So I can't reproduce the maps-related issue you have regarding the camera not updating upon place search. But that's not the issue here because your code for updating the camera works fine when placed within `viewDidLoad()`.

To resolve this I strongly recommend you use Google's Places SDK with Autocomplete instead of what you have there, see https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/autocomplete

Hope this helps!

Comment: 1. po self.mapView
▿ Optional<GMSMapView>
  - some : <GMSMapView: 0x104937800; frame = (0 105; 380 460); clipsToBounds = YES; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x28332c6f0>; layer = <GMSMapLayer: 0x283325e30>>
po self.longitude
73.8635912
po self.latitude
18.5018322

2. Tried with this step didn’t work.
3. They (Google map SDK) replace animateToLocation with animate(toLocation: coordinate), this also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude, longitude:  self.longitude)
let newCamera = GMSCameraUpdate.setTarget(coordinate)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setValue(2, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
    self.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: googleLocation!.lat, longitude: googleLocation!.long)
    CATransaction.commit()
    self.mapView?.animate(with: newCamera)
}
```

with this:

```
 camera = try GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude, zoom: 14.0)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setValue(2, forKey: kCATransactionAnimationDuration)
            self.marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: googleLocation!.lat, longitude: googleLocation!.long)
            self.marker.map?.animate(to: camera)
        CATransaction.commit()
    }
```

Thanks for support @evan